# Creating Coupon For First Two Products Free

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon

I have a category "Free Samples" and want the first 2 products in that category to be free and the rest to cost their original price.
So lets say the user adds these products to their cart:
sample1 - $8.00
sample2 - $8.00
sample3 - $8.00

sample1 and sample2 should be free and sample3 should $8.00
with the cart total being $8.
How can I do this using the Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head you could set up the rule so the condition is the specific set of products, or the products belong to the category.  The actions would be to discount 100% of the product price.  Limit that to 2 products as the maximum applied to.  Then save and refresh your cart.  You should see two $0.00 items and one $8.00 item.

Note that you will want to check multiple quantities being purchased of different items.  Make sure you test a bunch of different ways to try and "break" your rule, as someone somewhere will try it just to get free stuff.